# LocalizedPVSystem values

Tags: solar, pvlib

i have the following verified set of values for central London in 30min intervals (2015-2016):

```
Direct NI;Diffuse NI;Reflected;Global NI;Direct Horiz;Diffus Horiz;Global Horiz;Top of Atmosphere
```

this data is from [soda-pro.com](http://www.soda-pro.com/help/general/plane-orientations-and-radiation-components). the `wind_speed` and `temp_air` data is as well verified.

trying to create a simple pv generation model, i am not sure which values should be fed into the `total_irrad` function.
for `[dni, ghi, dhi]` i've tried `[Direct NI, Global Horiz, Direct Horiz]` but the values make no sense (556kWh yearly for a 1kW system).

replacing the `Direct NI` with `Global NI` resulted 765 kWh/year for the same system - a bit more reasonable i think - but i'm not sure if that's correct.

advice please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe "POA global" should be fed to the system. You can calculate POA using get_irradiance function from pvsystem.

reference : [link](http://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.pvsystem.PVSystem.get_irradiance.html)

Answer (score 0):

DNI = Direct Normal Irradiance

GHI = Global Horizontal Irradiance

DHI = Diffuse Horizontal Irradiance

For your dataset, [dni, ghi, dhi] = [Direct NI, Global Horiz, Diffus Horiz]